# test SQL outside of VBA ADODB connection

Tags: sql, excel, vba

As a follow up to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61528980/connect-to-a-worksheet-run-sql-query-and-output-to-new-worksheet), I was able to write a VBA script which successfully connects to a worksheet in the current workbook, executes an SQL query on the returned recordset and outputs the result of a query to another worksheet in the same workbook:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim connection As New ADODB.connection

    connection.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & ThisWorkbook.FullName & _
                    ";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;"";"

    Dim query As String
    query = "Select * From [Sheet1$]"

    Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset

    rs.Open query, connection

    Sheet2.Cells.ClearContents

    'Write Header
    Dim i As Long

    For i = 0 To rs.Fields.Count - 1
        Sheet2.Cells(1, i + 1).Value2 = rs.Fields(i).Name
    Next i

    Sheet2.Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rs
    connection.Close

End Sub
```

The issue is I am not sure which SQL statement I want to use. Therefore I am looking for a lightweight SQL command line tool or environment which would allow me to connect to the Microsoft ACE OLEDB database engine *outside* of excel and test out some SQL queries on the data imported by the recordset above. When I decide I have got the right query I can then paste it into the `query =` portion of my code above.

What lightweight tools exist which would allow me to explicitly connect to the ACE OLEDB data engine outside of excel and play around with the SQL before I go back into VBA?

Comment: It does state here that ActiveX data objects reference uses ANSI 92 SQL https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/using-activex-data-objects Not sure whether thats the sql flavor though...

Comment: Why don't you import the spreadsheet into Access? Then you can use the wizards to help you construct your query. Finally switch to SQL view and copy the resultant statement. That should guarantee that you have the right flavour of SQL.

Comment: @JonathanWillcock yes I think Access might be the way to go. However I prefer not to use wizards and would like to build up the SQL programmatically. I see this is possible in Access SQL view however there are some very annoying limitations, for instance it is not possible to have multiple SQL statements within one query. It is also not possible to comment things in or out....

Comment: You don't have to use the wizards. You can enter sql direct in the SQL View

Comment: Please see my previous comment regarding why I don't want to use the SQL view

Comment: AFAIK the restrictions that you get in Access SQL View apply to the ACE engine as well.  In particular you cannot use multiple statements, and there are restrictions on the complexity of queries.  Moreover, you need to use the same style of bracketing in building joins.